# Can I emulate previous versions of Firefox within Firefox 4.0?

Tags: firefox

The Developer Tools in IE 8 (and 9) allow switching Document and Browser Modes to previous versions.  Is that possible with Firefox 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not possible. It is possible to change the User-Agent string using the Add-on [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/), but it does not change the behavior of the Javascript engine.

Having two Firefox versions installed at a time is possible. Just choose a different installation folder. When running Firefox, use different profiles and pass the `--no-remote` option to prevent a new window being opened with the active Firefox application.

For example, you can create the profile "firefox36" and "firefox4" and run these using:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Firefox 4\firefox.exe" --no-remote -P firefox4
"%ProgramFiles%\Firefox 3.6\firefox.exe" --no-remote -P firefox36
```

Comment: On OSX you can have multiple versions installed, just make sure each has a different name (e.g. Firefox 3.app, Firefox.app etc). User profiles will conflict, which is only a pain if FF is your day to day browser. In that case, try MultiFirefox: http://davemartorana.com/multifirefox/